# Can't launch Intel XDK's debugger in emulator

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, node-webkit, intel-xdk

I got problems with Intel XDK: I can't launch debugger at emulator. Its interesting because debuggers in 'test' and 'debug' panels are alright. I tried to reinstall Node-Webkit,updated node.js, reinstall XDK-nothing worked. I use Ubuntu 14.04. May be anyone can help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The XDK uses it's own private copy of NodeJS that it has been tested against. Do not replace the copy of Node that is included inside the XDK install directory, it will cause problems with the product.

Are you able to open the Emulate tab on a simple blank project? Have you reported this on the Intel XDK forum?

Comment: I did nothin with XDK's included Node. I have no problem with opening of Emulate tab,i have problem with launching debugger in it, it opens for a few seconds and hides somewhere, I can't log it.

Comment: If I understand your comment, you're saying that the Chrome DevTools window disappears when you open it in the Emulate tab. Is that correct?

If that is the issue, this is something new, not seen it. Can you please take this issue to the [XDK forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk). We can handle it better there.

Comment: So, I solved this problem, i deleted everything  in ~/.config/XDK and reinstalled Intel XDK, it helped me,thanks @xmnboy for help